# How to install and start MediathekView on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: pi-4

Is it possible to install and run MediathekView on a RaspberryPi 4 with 4GB RAM and if so, how to do it?

Is this also possible with a RaspberryPi without a monitor attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the **arm**-architecture (for Raspberry Pi chip) as `.deb` from [here](https://mediathekview.de/download/) and run the installer (with `sudo`)

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://download.mediathekview.de/stabil/MediathekView-latest-linux-armhf.deb
dpkg -i MediathekView-latest-linux-armhf.deb
```

Check if the programm was installed with `ls /opt/MediathekView`. It should print the content of the directory:

```
bin  MediathekView          MediathekView.ico   MediathekView_ipv4.desktop    MediathekView.jar  MediathekView.vmoptions
jre  MediathekView.desktop  MediathekView_ipv4  MediathekView_ipv4.vmoptions  MediathekView.svg  README.txt
```

See how the installation includes a Java Runtime Environment in `jre`. Now run the startup command from the correct directory:

```
cd /opt/MediathekView
jre/bin/java -Xmx1G -jar MediathekView.jar
```

If it does not work try

```
jre/bin/java -Xmx1G --enable-preview -jar MediathekView.jar
```

### This should start up the program.

Note, that all of this is possible from a client that logs into a Pi via `VNC` that has no monitor attached. To to this use a client like [Remmina](https://remmina.org/). To set this up you might have to take some additional steps in the config for the graphics, but is is possible. I might adjust my answer accordingly in the future.

---

You also need to install the following:

```
sudo apt install vlc
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

and then set those paths in the configuration the first time the program runs and asks for it:

```
/usr/bin/vlc
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

---

While downloading one file the RaspberryPi uses 30% of the 4GB RAM and about 100% of CPU. With [this](https://www.amazon.de/Sertronics-Armor-Geh%C3%A4use-Raspberry-schwarz/dp/B07VP6GB4G) passive cooler the core temperature was about 48°C:

```
vcgencmd measure_temp
```